# ElasticSearch and existing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc, elasticsearch

I have MySQL database with data. There is a many-to-many relationship in the database - parent, child and reference tables.
I'd like to add fulltext search functionality. I wonder if elasticsearch can help me. I have found [jdbc](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) plugin. As I understand I have to index the my existing data using the following code:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
        "user" : "",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "any complex sql query, it can be select from 3 tables"
    }
}'
```

So I have the following questions:

1. It doesnt matter what kind of database scheme I have. I just have
   to provide an sql query and elasticsearch index the obtained data.
   Is it right?
2. What do I have to do when I add new data? I should
   add new record in two places? In sql database and elastichsearch
   index? Is it correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracts from the documentation [river documentation](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc):

1. The scheme doesn't matter, the results of the query will be converted into a valid Elasticsearch JSON:

   [image]

will result into the following JSON documents:

```
id=<random> {"product":"Apples","created":null,"department":"American Fruits","quantity":1,"customer":"Big"}
id=<random> {"product":"Bananas","created":null,"department":"German Fruits","quantity":1,"customer":"Large"}
id=<random> {"product":"Oranges","created":null,"department":"German Fruits","quantity":2,"customer":"Huge"}
id=<random> {"product":"Apples","created":1338501600000,"department":"German Fruits","quantity":2,"customer":"Good"}
id=<random> {"product":"Oranges","created":1338501600000,"department":"English Fruits","quantity":3,"c
```

2. It is recommended to use timestamps in UTC for synchronization. This example fetches all product rows which has added since the last river run, using a millisecond resolution column mytimestamp:

   ```
   {
       "type" : "jdbc",
       "jdbc" : {
           "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
           "user" : "",
           "password" : "",
           "sql" : [
               {
                   "statement" : "select * from \"products\" where \"mytimestamp\" > ?",
                   "parameter" : [ "$river.state.last_active_begin" ]
               }
           ],
           "index" : "my_jdbc_river_index",
           "type" : "my_jdbc_river_type"
       }
   }
   ```